# how to edit a PDF in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, pdf

i'm writing an application in objective-c (using cocoa). i have a PDF template, i need to substitute actual values into placeholders in PDF and then save the result into new PDF.

how can i do it? which library should i use?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've found the solution! It connects the power of quartz2d and simplicity of UIGraphics.

```
NSString *newFilePath = @"path/to/your/newfile.pdf";
NSString *templatePath = @"path/to/your/template.pdf";

//create empty pdf file;
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(newFilePath, CGRectMake(0, 0, 792, 612), nil);

CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath (NULL, (CFStringRef)templatePath, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, 0);

//open template file
CGPDFDocumentRef templateDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);
CFRelease(url);

//get amount of pages in template
size_t count = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(templateDocument);

//for each page in template
for (size_t pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= count; pageNumber++) {
    //get bounds of template page
    CGPDFPageRef templatePage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(templateDocument, pageNumber);
    CGRect templatePageBounds = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(templatePage, kCGPDFCropBox);

    //create empty page with corresponding bounds in new document
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(templatePageBounds, nil);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //flip context due to different origins
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, templatePageBounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    //copy content of template page on the corresponding page in new file
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, templatePage);

    //flip context back
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, templatePageBounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    /* Here you can do any drawings */
    [@"Test" drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(200, 300) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
}
CGPDFDocumentRelease(templateDocument);
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably [PDFKit](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html).  For some tasks, the high level PDFKit API cannot do what you want, and you might be forced to use the low level [CG PDF parsing libraries](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf_scan/dq_pdf_scan.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH220-TPXREF101).  They're quite low level, though.  They mean really understanding the PDF file format.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question is about obj-c, but if you are here because of the **edit pdf**, below there is a solution in **Swift 3**:

PS: In my solution I needed to edit the document info of the new PDF, so I used the **subject parameter** to do this.

```
func createPDF(on path: String?, from templateURL: URL?, with subject: String?) {
    guard let newPDFPath = path,
        let pdfURL = templateURL else { return }

    let options = [(kCGPDFContextSubject as String): subject ?? ""] as CFDictionary

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(newPDFPath, .zero, options as? [AnyHashable : Any])

    let templateDocument = CGPDFDocument(pdfURL as CFURL)
    let pageCount = templateDocument?.numberOfPages ?? 0

    for i in 1...pageCount {

        //get bounds of template page
        if let templatePage = templateDocument?.page(at: i) {
            let templatePageBounds = templatePage.getBoxRect(.cropBox)

            //create empty page with corresponding bounds in new document
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(templatePageBounds, nil)
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

            //flip context due to different origins
            context?.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: templatePageBounds.height)
            context?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

            //copy content of template page on the corresponding page in new file
            context?.drawPDFPage(templatePage)

            //flip context back
            context?.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: templatePageBounds.height)
            context?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        }
    }
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
}
```