# iOS - searching and replacing on a PDF

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have to create a PDF file based on a template. My idea is to build that template with placeholders like "text1", "text2", etc. This template would be saved to a PDF file and put on the app bundle.

At run time, the template would be copied to a new PDF context and then I would search for the placeholders, replacing them with the real text I want.

[I have found this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333710/how-to-edit-a-pdf-in-objective-c), showing how to create a new PDF from a template and [this one](http://blog.random-ideas.net/?p=184) on how to search on the PDF.

The question now is: how do I replace stuff (texts or images) on the new PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really not that simple, Unless the replacement text is the same length as the template.

If the replacement is the same length as the template, you can use the methods highlighted in the first link you provided and then just use core graphics to draw the replacement at the correct location for the coordinate.

If the replacement text is variable, then you are trying to insert the text into the old pdf. As far as i know, this is non-trivial, unless you use very low level libraries like libharu.

Here is an alternative solution for you, which may suit your needs, and which I am using.

Firstly, store your template as a HTML file.
Put placeholders in your HTML file for the text you will replace.
Load the template, replace the text, then use the following method to get your pdf.

```
NSString *html = @"<html><head></head><body>all my awesome html</body></html>"
```

Create a PDF context to data.

```
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData( pdfData, CGRectMake(0, 0, kPDFPageWidth, kPDFPageHeight), nil );
```

create a markup text print formatter, in this case the parameter html is your fully replaced html template page.

```
 UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter *fmt = [[UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc]
                                           initWithMarkupText:html];
```

The markup formatter is what apple provide for you to print html, but you can also use it to print a pdf. You need to subclass a UIPrintPageRenderer in order to do this. So assume you have created your subclass, here is what the rest of the call will look like, Ill show you the subclass below.

```
PDFPrintPageRenderer *renderer = [[PDFPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];


        // Render the html into a PDF
        [renderer addPrintFormatter:fmt startingAtPageAtIndex:0];
        [renderer printToPDF:1];
```

print to pdf is a call that takes the number of pages you want to print. If you don't know this in advance, the best way to make sure it all looks nice, is to have your template broken into pages, and to perform this process for each page. Anyway, after this call, you should have a pdf which you can save out with the following.

```
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    //store the pdf
    [pdfData writeToFile:basePath atomically:YES];
```

Here is the subclassed renderer that I use.

```
#define kPDFPageWidth 595
#define kPDFPageHeight 842

@interface PDFPrintPageRenderer : UIPrintPageRenderer
@property (nonatomic) BOOL generatingPDF;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger heightCount;
- (NSData*) printToPDF:(NSInteger) height;
@end
```

implementation

```
@implementation PDFPrintPageRenderer
@synthesize generatingPDF;
@synthesize heightCount;

- (CGRect) paperRect
{
    if (!generatingPDF)
        return [super paperRect];

    return UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds();
}

- (CGRect) printableRect
{
    if (!generatingPDF)
        return [super printableRect];

    return CGRectInset( self.paperRect, 5, 5 );
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfPages {
    if (!generatingPDF) {
        return [super numberOfPages];
    }

    return self.heightCount;
}

- (NSData*) printToPDF:(NSInteger) height
{
    self.heightCount = height;
    generatingPDF = YES;



    [self prepareForDrawingPages: NSMakeRange(0, self.numberOfPages)];

    CGRect bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds();


    for ( int i = 0 ; i < self.numberOfPages; i++ )
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

        [self drawPageAtIndex: i inRect: bounds];

    }


    generatingPDF = NO;

    return nil;
}

@end
```

let me know if you have questions, or if it helped, or if it didn't.

Comment: ah, I see, the strings have to be the same length... that makes things impossible... anyway your code helps a lot to understand how it works. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible. You can either take the image of that text which text you want to replace.

like there is two text-

text1 = actual text in pdf
text2 = the text which you want to put in pdf by replacing text1

now take the imageview of text2 And set the image of that text instead of image of text1.
First you need to search for text1 and take the image of that text. then only you can replace 
the image of text1 with text2.
And one thing more you need to ensure that you can't change the text directly. you have to take the images of that text and you can only replace images.

And another thing is to catch that text in image of pdf you can use the exact point in drwaing with the help of cgpoint. So by the help of the x and y coordinates you can catch that text which you want to replace.

Comment: sorry but my brain melted after the second line. Can you please add some code to show this in action? Thanks.